# How to get image from recyclerview position clicked data and set it into another imageview?

Tags: android

I have an app which contains `recyclerview` with `imageview` and text.When I click on item based on position that is `imageview` i want image of that image view and set it to another `Imageview`.To do this I have made `interface` and implements its method in `Activity` but need to know that how do i do that

Adapter code:

```
  public interface OnItemClicked {
    void onItemClicked(int position);
}

public AvatarListAdapter(Context context, int[] arrayList) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.dataModel = arrayList;
}

@Override
public AvatarListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.avatar_items, parent, false);
    return new AvatarListAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AvatarListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.mAvatarImage.setImageResource(dataModel[position]);
    holder.mAvatarImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClick.onItemClicked(position);
        }
    });
}

public void setOnClick(OnItemClicked onClick) {
    this.onClick = onClick;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataModel.length;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private CircleImageView mAvatarImage;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mAvatarImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_avatar);
    }
}
}
```

Activity code:

```
  private void initializeActions() {
    int numberOfColumns = 3;
    mAvatarImages.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(AvatarProfileImage.this, numberOfColumns));
    mAdapter = new AvatarListAdapter(AvatarProfileImage.this, avatar);
    mAvatarImages.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mAdapter.setOnClick(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClicked(int position) {
    String pos = "You clicked at position " + position;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked position" + pos, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mAvatarImages.setBackgroundResource(avatar[position]);
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you want ? what is problem ?

Comment: I want to get image from   private static int[] avatar = {R.drawable.boy, R.drawable.boy_1, R.drawable.boy_2, R.drawable.boy_3,  and set it to image view

Comment: yeah, I see you have done.  You get the position return when item clicked and you have int[] avatar. Now you can get the image and set to whatever image view you want

Comment: Means, you want to use this image in any dialog, fragment or activity?

Answer (score 2):

You can get data by position on `OnClick()`.As you are using local drawable for image resource,  One way to do is Modify your viewHolder as follows.This is just a one way you can also use `ViewTag`.

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    private Circle mAvatarImage;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mAvatarImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_avatar);
        mAvatarImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int postion =getAdapterPosition();
        int image =arrayList[postion];
        // Use this image to forward

    }
}
```

Remove `OnClick` from `onBindViewHolder`.

Answer (score 2):

Implement `RecycleView` `onClick()` method and get specified data while `onclick` position.have look

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    private Circle mAvatarImage;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mAvatarImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_avatar);
        mAvatarImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int position=arrayList[getAdapterPosition()];
        String imagepath = arraylist.get(position).getImagePath       
        //you can use imagepath anywhere you want either be put in bundle or intent call

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapter code should look like this

```
    private final OnItemClickListener listenerOnItemClick;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position); }

    public AvatarListAdapter(Context context, int[] arrayList, OnItemClickListener listenerOnItemClick) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.dataModel = arrayList;     
        this.listenerOnItemClick=listenerOnItemClick;
    }

    @Override 
    public AvatarListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.avatar_items, parent, false);
        return new AvatarListAdapter.ViewHolder(view); }

    @Override 
    public void onBindViewHolder(AvatarListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.mAvatarImage.setImageResource(dataModel[position]);
        holder.mAvatarImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onClick.onItemClicked(position);
            }
        }); }

        public void setOnClick(OnItemClicked onClick) {
        this.onClick = onClick; }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
        return dataModel.length; }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private CircleImageView mAvatarImage;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mAvatarImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_avatar);
        } }
```

Activity Code

```
       AvatarListAdapter.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener = new AvatarListAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {
                //change your Image here
            String pos = "You clicked at position " + position;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked position" + pos, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mAvatarImages.setBackgroundResource(avatar[position]);
            }
        };




     private void initializeActions() {
        int numberOfColumns = 3;
        mAvatarImages.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(AvatarProfileImage.this, numberOfColumns));
        mAdapter = new AvatarListAdapter(AvatarProfileImage.this, avatar,onItemClickListener );
        mAvatarImages.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.setOnClick(this);
    }
```